# Functions don't return multiple values from lists Python

Tags: python, list, function

```
MyHand =[1,2,3]

def DisplayCards(location):
  for elm in location:
    if elm <= 4:
      return(elm)

print(DisplayCards(MyHand))
```

I'm working on a poker game in python and im working on a function that will show cards and a simplified version of my function is shown. In the example code all of 1,2, and 3 are true but the code will only return 1, hoe do i get my code to return all 3?

Comment: If you want to return multiple, you could consider saving them to a new list and returning that list.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
MyHand =[1,2,3]

def DisplayCards(location):
   return [x for x in location if x < 4] 


print(DisplayCards(MyHand))
```